# How to render code blocks exactly as-is in django

Tags: django, django-templates

How would I render the following properly?

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-markdown">
        {% autoescape off %}
        <Item>hello</Item>
        {% endautoescape %}
    </code>
</pre>
```

Basically, I want it to show the xml, like:

```
<Item>Hello</Item>
```

And not try and strip the tags. Instead, it just prints "Hello" without the tags. Note, the `verbatim` tag does not work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in a view with `django.utils.html.escape` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape

Or write a template tag that does the escaping using this function.

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import escape

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def escape_html(value):
    return escape(value)
```